# Error importing build in iTunes Connect for tvOS binary

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, tvos

I'm trying to submit a new app but every binary that I upload to iTunes Connect is marked with the following error:

> There was an error importing this build. We are working to resolve the issue.

I've tried uploading through both xCode and Application Loader but the error persists.

Is anyone experiencing this?

Update:

Forgot to mention that I also found people experiencing the same issue on the Apple Developer Forum: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25377

Comment: this question will get more responses on apple discussion board.

Comment: Thanks @SamB. I forgot to mention that I had already found this on the apple dev forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25377